# Azure can not find python version

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

When I try to run func init  for azure core tools I get the error "Could not find a Python version" but when I run az --version, it shows that it detects python 3.6 as required.

[image: Issue seen here]

Comment: probably means python3.exe is not on the path. does it recognize `python3.exe` or `python.exe` if you just type it in the terminal?

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Comment: If my answer helps you, can you mark it as the answer of this question?:) [Link about how to mark answer](https://0730bowmanwindow.blob.core.windows.net/work/mark.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This python is installed with the Azure Cli, however it's not set to the system path.
So now your choice is to download a new python installation package it will set path for you.

Another choice is you the Cli Python, cause it already give you the python directory, so just add the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2` to the path, then you will be able to use python in the command line.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, please make sure you have installed python3.6 or python3.7.

If you don't install python you will get the same result as your screenshot, like this:

[image]

Please download python3.6 or python3.7 on the python offcial website and install. What your screenshot showed can not mean the python is installed.

Second, please add the python path to the env variable. After add the env variable, remember to restart your computer otherwise the env varible will not work.

This is my env variable configuration of python:

[image]

After that, you can create python function app successfully.

[image]

[image]